# How to read Cacti RRD Files and save it to CSV file using python

Tags: python, json, rrd, cacti

I currently use cacti as the monitory platform. I need to read the collected data saved in rrd files and put it in a CSV to transform it to JSON format (It will be put in a map) using Python.

How could I get the data from the rrd using python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried 'rrd2csv'?

Comment: I will try! I found this info https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/Rrd2csv